# To Babel or Not - Confused

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I don't know with web apps if you still have to use Babel if Node 4 is out which supports ES6 so why would I need babel anymore for any web related code?  Or maybe I don't?

I see most apps are using babel but I wonder if people are pulling it out now or is there middleware people typically use in web apps that still rely on it, thus you have to keep it and keep using babel?

Comment: NodeJS supports *most* ES6 features on the server-side. It doesn't support module export syntax for example. Any JS code you send to the client side still needs transpiled to Babel.

Answer (score 1):

Node v4 doesn't support the full feature set of ES2015 (aka ES6). For those that aren't supported you still can use Babel. You can find a list of node's support of ES2015 features [in this page](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/).

You say "web related code", which is too broad, but I assume you're interested in browser support as well. No browser supports all ES2015 features yet, so you should use a transpiler like Babel. You can find a [table of feature compatibility here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

You will also find that no transpiler has full support either, so be careful when introducing new features.

It's not likely that projects will stop using transpilers yet. Even less so if they want to support older versions of node.

Comment: A year later and now the major browsers are 92% ES6 compatible. Node v6 is 97% ES6 compatible. It seems the only big piece missing is ES6 module syntax in Node.